# Creating image and loading it in the page

Tags: php, image, content-type

I want to create/generate an image with `PHP`, adding text into it, but without saving it into the FTP, I'd like to load it on the site by changing the content type to `image/png`, the same way I did it with `ASP.NET`:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
rImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

I found a function called `file_put_contents`, but I'm not so sure this is what I'm looking for. If you know how to do something like this, please tell me.

I'm trying this code, but it fails to load the image, and shows the browser's default error image.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Saving to output is only a detail. The most trouble will be generating an image. So you have to find a way to translate "`rImage`" to PHP.

Comment: @GolezTrol I found a way, but it shows me a broken image.

Comment: Maybe GD is not installed in your PHP.

Comment: It is, I checked with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Oh nevermind, had to use `ob_clean()` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Below example will regenerate an image with text over it:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png"); // Set the header so that browser can output the image
$string = 'Print this text on Image'; // Text to be added on the image
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png"); // Take base image
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60); // Allocate a color for an image

imagestring($im, 3, 0, 0, $string, $orange); // Write the string at the top left
imagepng($im); // Create new image
imagedestroy($im); // destroy object

?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php